# extending python logging module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to extend python(2.7)'s logging module (and specifically the logger class).

Currently I have:

```
class MyLogger(logging.Logger):

    def __init__(self, name):
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name)
```

1. Is this the right way to initialize MyLogger?
2. Will I be able to use Logger.manager (logging.Logger.manager)?
3. Is it possible to "get" a logger (I only know logging.getLogger(name) - which is not available since I'm extending the Logger itself, and I know static methods aren't popular in python as they are in Java, for example)?
4. Where can I learn more about extending classes? The documentation in [python.org](http://python.org) is very poor and did not help me.

My goal is to be able to start a logger with standard configurations and handlers based on the caller module's name, and to set the entire system loggers to the same level with a short, readable, call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my approach was wrong altogether.

I prefer the [way](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules) stated in [python.org](http://python.org):

Using configuration files for the cleans up code and allows to propagate changes easily.

A configuration file is loaded like so:

```
# view example on python.org site (logging for multiple modules)
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

As for batch abilities, since we keep logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict and logging.getLogger, batch operations can use simple loops to create changes (like setting loggers to a single level) throughout the system.